# XPath to concatenate parent and child attribute values in one query

Tags: xml, xpath, xpathnavigator

Given:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<report Id="0" >
<property name="comments">comment</property>
<property name="test">sdcs</property>
<property name="test">csd</property>
<property name="eventHandlerClass">sdcs</property>
</report>
<report  Id="1">
<property name="comments">comment</property>
<property name="test">dcs</property>
<property name="test">gds</property>
<property name="test">jds</property>
<property name="eventHandlerClass">sdcs</property>
</report>
</root>
```

Expected output:

```
Id=0, test=sdcs
Id=0, test=csd
Id=1, test=dcs
Id=1, test=gds
Id=1, test=jds
```

Only looking for a plain Xpath ***1.0*** to achieve this. Tried varioud functions and predicates but fail to get an output like above.
Essentially, after reading I should be able to tell which "test" belongs to which report Id.

Tried:

`/root/report/@Id | /root/report/property[@name="test"]`
-- But gives result in separate lines

`/root/report/ ( @Id | property[@name="test"])` -- But gives result in separate lines

`concat( /root/report/@Id, /root/report/property[@name="test"])`  -- Gives error (think Concat works on single line result)

`string-join(/root/report/@Id | /root/report/property[@name="test"]  , ',')`  -- All comes as a single line, even two report Ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for for that to keep the id in a variable:

```
for $report in /root/report 
return for $property in $report/property[@name="test"]
return concat("Id=", $report/@Id, ", ", $property/@name, "=", $property)
```

Or shorter:

```
for $report in /root/report return
$report/property[@name="test"]/
concat("Id=", $report/@Id, ", ", @name, "=", .)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! But, unfortunately not available in XPath 1.0!!

Comment: I do not think it is possible in XPath 1 since you can select every node only once, and values only at the end. Unless there is a hard limit on the size (e.g. only two report nodes) (and your 2nd example is XPath 2, not 1, isn't it?)

Comment: Yes, it is XPath 2. I was trying all different options without checking at the actual system. With your solution realized that I have a limitation to use XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this quite elegantly with by making the primary "iteration elements" be the deepest child - in this example the XML root-element is TABLE. See how we "iterate" over the deeper child called COLUMN. We take the COLUMN's @name (second), and add the parent's-parent's @name attribute

```
/TABLE/COLUMNS/COLUMN/concat(../../@name, ' : ', @name)
```

This eliminates the need to use a variable for the parent's @name